# SOAP Request data is not going to External System in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, soap-client, soapserver

I am trying to send request data to external soap server but data is going to null in the request to External Soap Server.

Please find the code as below:

```
UserListResponse response = null;

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "UserList")
@ResponsePayload
public UserListResponse UserListRequest(@RequestPayload UserListRequest request) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Enters into UserList()");
    try {


       //Client call

       UserServicesLocator locator = new UserServicesLocator();
       UserServicesSoapStub stub = (UserServicesSoapStub) locator.getUserServicesSoap();

        response = stub.userList(request);//here the request data values not mapping at external system side

        } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return response;
}
```

## SOAP UI Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prim="http://*****/UserServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <prim:UserList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <prim:XMLRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Header>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:MessageID>1</prim:MessageID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:CorrelationID>1</prim:CorrelationID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:SystemID>C</prim:SystemID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:RequestorID>1</prim:RequestorID>
            </prim:Header>
            <prim:Reference>Account</prim:Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Number>100987600</prim:Number>

         </prim:XMLRequest>
      </prim:UserList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The request is hitting the External Soap server but Soap server getting the all values (both Header & Body data)in the request as null.

I am unable to get why the values are going to null even i am passing the values from SOAP UI.

I am not getting even i am doing anything wrong here.Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Does the service requires credentials? Your  ` <soapenv:Header/>` is empty.

Comment: credentials Not required,we able to hit the server and getting the response. Header does means <prim:Header> and body going to the server as null. Thanks @ Luis Muñoz